# How can I use my python app using WIndows?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, docker

I have one python app which use the following modules :

```
- matplotlib
- tkinter
- pylab
- numpy 
- ...
```

This python app works perfectly with Linux but I would like to use this using Windows. I saw there is some modules which allows to compile my python code but I try and I get some errors. That is why I thought to two things :

- Using something like docker with Windows and then install Linux on Docker and use my python app but my python app use Tkinter and I thought docker works only with terminal there is no GUI
- Using a website to put my python code on the web and then allow to use my python code with any OS. I thought to do this using Django but I don't know if I could do this and mostly if it will work.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Depending on your audience, the simplest solution might just be to install Python and your dependencies on Windows using the dependency manager of your choice (probably `pip` or Pipenv). Have you tried that? Is there a reason that this won't work for you?

Comment: Actually yes there are lots of dependencies and it is a waste of time to install all the dependencies...

Comment: did you try cx-Freeze or pyinstaller?